# Lambda calculus Beta reduction

Tags: lambda-calculus

When applying Beta reduction does the function also affect on the $\lambda$ term? (If same value)

For example

> $\lambda$ z.$\lambda$ z (z z) t

What is the correct reduction?

$\lambda$z (t t) or

$\lambda$t (t t)

Comment: How is `λz.λz (z z) t` parsed? Is it `λz.(λz (z z) t)` or `(λz.λz (z z)) t`?

Comment: it is `(λz.λz (z z)) t`

Comment: Then you get $\lambda u\, (u\; u)$. Of course instead of $u$, you can call the variable anything you like, e.g. $t$ or $z$. Note that $\lambda z.\, \lambda z\, (z\; z) \equiv \lambda z.\, \lambda y\, (y\; y)$.

Answer (score 0):

The beta contraction of $(\lambda x . M)\, N$ is defined as $[N/x]\, M$, and recall that the substitution is done by replacing every *free* instance of $x$ by $N$.

Explicitly, $(\lambda z. (\lambda z. zz))t \triangleright_\beta [t/z]\,(\lambda z. zz)$, but as there is no free occurence of $z$ no substitution is performed.